# Pip not retrieving the latest version of a package: Google Colab

Tags: python, pip, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to use the google-ads package in Google Colab, I use the magic method

```
%pip install google-ads
```

The downloaded version is 4.0.0, but the current version in pypi.org is the [7.0.0](https://pypi.org/project/google-ads/), is there any way to download the newest version?
Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 2):

I've found the problem, the package google-ads 7.0.0 requires python>= 3.7, colab uses 3.6.9

Answer (score 0):

type the following command

```
pip install google-ads==7.0.0
```

Comment: I tried, gives me this error: 
`ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement google-ads==7.0.0 (from versions:...`
`ERROR: No matching distribution found for google-ads==7.0.0`